Sync Audio with Video in react
I have an audio file of .3 seconds and video. I want to sync audio with video. Whenever video plays audio plays in a loop. whenever we change the playback rate of the video, the audio's playback rate also changes. But the issue is that whenever I change the video playback rate from 1x to any value. I can't hear the audio due to its time duration. Is there any way we can play audio faster or slower as the video's playback rate increases or decreases?
I have tried first to make context, decode audio, and use a buffer to change the audio playback rate using web audio API. But, the audio is playing way faster at the normal rate.
import { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import styles from "./home.module.css";
// import audioSrc from "../../assets/audio2.mp3";
import audioSrc from "../../assets/impact.wav";
import videoSrc from "../../assets/video.mp4";

const Home = () => {
  const videoRef = useRef(null);
  const audioContextRef = useRef(null);
  const audioBufferRef = useRef(null);
  const sourceNodeRef = useRef(null);

  use effect(() => {
    const initializeAudio = async () => {
      try {
        // Initialize the AudioContext
        audioContextRef.current = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

        // Fetch and decode the audio file
        const response = await fetch(audioSrc);
        const arrayBuffer = await response.array buffer();
        const audioBuffer = await audioContextRef.current.decodeAudioData(array buffer);

        audioBufferRef.current = audio buffer;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error loading or decoding audio:", error);
      }
    };

    initializeAudio();

    return () => {
      if (sourceNodeRef.current) {
        sourceNodeRef.current.stop();
      }
      if (audioContextRef.current) {
        audioContextRef.current.close();
      }
    };
  }, []);

  const handle play = () => {
    if (sourceNodeRef.current) {
      sourceNodeRef.current.stop();
    }

    sourceNodeRef.current = audioContextRef.current.createBufferSource();
    sourceNodeRef.current.buffer = audioBufferRef.current;
    sourceNodeRef.current.playbackRate.value = videoRef.current.playback rate;
    sourceNodeRef.current.connect(audioContextRef.current.destination);
    sourceNodeRef.current.loop = true;
    // Synchronize audio start time with video
    sourceNodeRef.current.start(0, video ref.current.currentTime);
  };

  const handlePause = () => {
    if (sourceNodeRef.current) {
      sourceNodeRef.current.stop();
    }
  };

  const handleVideoPlaybackRateChange = () => {
    const newPlaybackRate = videoRef.current.playbackRate;
    if (sourceNodeRef.current) {
      // Adjust playback rate and pitch
      sourceNodeRef.current.playbackRate.value = newPlaybackRate;

      // Adjust the pitch based on the new playback rate
      const detuneAmount = (Math.log2(newPlaybackRate) * 1200);
      sourceNodeRef.current.detune.value = detuneAmount;
    }
  };

  const handleVideoEnded = () => {
    if (sourceNodeRef.current) {
      sourceNodeRef.current.stop();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const video = videoRef.current;

    video.addEventListener("play", handlePlay);
    video.addEventListener("pause", handlePause);
    video.addEventListener("ratechange", handleVideoPlaybackRateChange);
    video.addEventListener("ended", handleVideoEnded);

    return () => {
      video.removeEventListener("play", handlePlay);
      video.removeEventListener("pause", handlePause);
      video.removeEventListener("ratechange", handleVideoPlaybackRateChange);
      video.removeEventListener("ended", handleVideoEnded);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <video ref={videoRef} src={videoSrc} controls className={styles.video} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;

